# Stack with id [existing stack] does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Stack XXX was created and deployed without issue. I updated a dependency and now want to redeploy it, but when I call `sls deploy`, it returns `Stack with id YYY does not exist`. However, stack YYY does exist, and in the same region as stack XXX.

I've deleted the S3 file for stack YYY and redeployed it, which didn't fix the problem. Other people have talked about `sls remove` causing the issue, but I haven't called that on either stack. I've also read that the problem might be the soft limit of 100 buckets in S3, but I'm not approaching that.

This is where and how stack YYY is referenced within XXX:

```
functions:
  firstFunctionName:
    handler: ./handler.firstFunction
    environment:
      CONTENT_TABLE: ${cf:YYY.ContentTable}
```

I expect `sls deploy` to run without issue. Here is the error message with environment info:

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Stack with id YYY does not exist

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     OS:                     win32
     Node Version:           10.15.3
     Serverless Version:     1.46.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem:

I ran a test that set `env AWS_REGION=us-west-1`, and then tried to deploy in the same terminal instance. My Serverless template sets `region: ${opt:region, env:AWS_REGION, 'us-east-2'}`, so I usually just let it default because that's the desired region. But because `env:AWS_REGION` had been set by the test, it was deploying to a region that in fact did not have the stack I was referencing.

The alternatives would be to run tests in `us-east-2` or, preferably, to always pass in the region when running deploy (e.g. `sls deploy --stage dev --region us-east-2`).